# sending multiple checkboxes and its associated select-field with php mail

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a table in a form. i like to send this table with a php script. and it should list all checked boxes, they have all a unique product-nr. (in the value-atribute) and a select field to chose the quantity.

how can i achieve this structure in the mail:

Name: John Doe XVV

E-Mail: xyz@xyz.com

Produkt:  (from value:) 142547 or something like that...

Stückzahl: (from select) 5

### or any other atribute that was in the table...

Produkt:   1414...

Stückzahl:  12

### color: green

Produkt:   14258-UI...

### Stückzahl:  8

Nachricht: 
hello...

each table line have the plain description and these 2 fiels at the end:

```
 <select class="1-100" name="menge[]" value="Stueckzahl"></select> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="14258-UI">
```

this is my php

```
$submitted  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['scf_submitted'] );
$name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['scf_name'] );
$email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['scf_email'] );
$message = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['scf_message'] );
$honeypot = $_POST['scf_message2'];
//$product = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['checkboxes'] );//
//$quantity = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['menge'] );//
$product = implode(' ', $_POST['checkboxes'] );
$quantity = implode(' ', $_POST['menge'] );
$body = "Name: $name \n\nE-Mail: $email \n\nProdukt: $product \n\nStückzahl: $quantity \n\nNachricht: \n$message";
```

i hope somebody can help me - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by iterating form lines on php handler like;

```
<?php
// You need to do some sanitization for posted fields

.............
$propArr = array(
    "menge" => "Menge",
    "checkbox" => "Checkbox",
    "other_attr" => "Other Attribute"
);

$html = "";
foreach($_POST["menge"] as $key => $val) {
    foreach($propArr as $k => $v) {
        $html .= "\n\n".$propArr[$k].":".$_POST[$k][$key];
    }
}

$body = $html;
?>
```

Comment: Is this correct:$product = implode .sanitize_text_field(' ', $_POST['checkboxes[]'] );

Comment: That is false. You need to sanitize `$_POST[$k][$key]` inside second loop